# Replace an array (with identical values) with another array in the_content

Tags: php, array, the-content

I'm making a plugin where I need to edit the H2 tags in the post content.

I've been at it for two days, but my php knowledge is too limited to solve the issue..

What I want to achieve is to return all `<h2>` tags as `<h2 id="$headings_array_stripped">`

What I can't seem to figure out is how to do this. I've tried combinations with `foreach` loops and `preg_replace`, `str_replace` and sorts.

The issue seems that the values inside the `$headings_open_tag_array` are all the same (`<h2>`) , so `str_replace`, for example, won't cycle through them, but only changes all `<h2>`'s to the first corresponding value of `$headings_array_stripped`:

`str_replace( $headings_open_tag_array, $headingsarray_stripped, $article )`

The code:

```
function replace_content_jump_menu() {

// Get metadata attached to the plugin
$jump_menu_check = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'jump-menu', true );

// Get the content
$article = get_the_content();

// Retrieve all <h2>header</h2> tags (with content) and put them in an array
preg_match_all( '|<h2>(.*)</h2>|iU', $article, $headings_array ); 

// Strip h2 tags and make lowercase
$headings_array_stripped = preg_replace( '/\W+|[0-9]+|\<h2\>|\<\/h2\>/', '', array_map( 'strtolower', $headings_array[0] ) ); 

// Retrieve all <h2> tags from the_content and put them in an array
preg_match_all( '|<h2>|iU', $article, $headings_open_tag_array ); 

// preg_replace? str_replace? foreach()?

};
add_filter( 'the_content', 'replace_content_jump_menu' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article by Jeroen Sormani](https://jeroensormani.com/automatically-add-ids-to-your-headings/) which solved my problem